# Parallel Pattern, an alternative to setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads and MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: c#, vb.net, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I often find myself running parallel web requests, and find there is a maximum amount of parallel requests the network connection can handle, so set MaxDegreeOfParallelism and run a parallel.for loop, example:

```
Dim maxThreads As Integer = 20 'pre tested optimum amount that wont overload network
Parallel.For(0, items.Count, New ParallelOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads}, Sub(i)
    'network stuff
    'eg Dim source As String = New Net.WebClient.DownloadString(items(i)) etc
    End Sub
```

As the network tasks are slow to complete, the thread count invariably rises to the max set, so it makes sense to start it at that by setting the threadpool minimum threads to the same amount (maxThreads).

This works fine, and is nice and readable, but i wonder if there isnt a better implementation, or if there is some inherent flaw in this approach.

.Net 4.5 introduces some great async support, but unfortunately i am limited to .net 4.
Any pointers appreciated, and yes this is vb.net but c# answers are fine.

Comment: Maybe you could try using the [`Async` marked methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of the threads, or combine it with [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx)? :) It would be more in line with `async-await` from .NET 4.5...

Comment: Why dont you give the Async Targetting Pack for .Net a try? You can stick with FW4 and still use Async/Await. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576

Comment: .net 4 Async really is messy, though i should probably carry out some tests to see if performance is worth the loss in readability. @ igrimpe im stuck with vs2010 as well, but thanks anyway, i did not know about that